# What control is used in Visual Studio ToolBox panel?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, user-controls

Please, read the header.
Need to do the same. What is that? TreeView, ListView, ToolboxContainer?

In fact it's called ToolBoxPane class and it's located and docked inside GenericPane class.

Are they the specific MS VS controls?

[image]

Comment: Why would Microsoft write Visual Studio using Visual Studio? It's terrible.

Answer (score 1):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winexplorerbar.aspx#Overview) calls it an ExplorerBar, but if you click on the video there are different looks available. One of which matches the Toolbox.

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/treeview.aspx) has a Treeview, which can certainly be customized to replicate the look of the Toolbox.

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/NavBar/) has a NavBar, which again can replicate that look.

I'm sure there are more, but that's a cursory search for WinForms controls (which I'm assuming is what you want, based on your screen shot).

Comment: I think he wants to know the baseclass so he has a good start for duplicating.

Comment: @Skomski - There isn't a base class that can be used, as that control is not available by Microsoft.

Comment: I like the ToolBarPane, as it has cool Drag&Drop func, it is very smart, lightweight, dockable...